# Save negative double in mysql database

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to create record with this data in mysql db with laravel (for example):

```
 $data=[[chatid] => -1001412042053
[title] => 'Bdd_grp'
[type] => 1]]
Model::create($data);
```

but `chatid` field will be saved as another number for example `-684662113` !!! why it happens? `chatid` datatype in mysql is `double`.

Comment: PHP datatype isn’t double. But “chatid” would hint at an indentifier, why is it double? Or is the naming just misleading?

Comment: Before inserting chatid into database, you may have been typecasting it as `(int)`, in your PHP code. Instead of that; typecast it as `(float)`. You current chatid value is out of integer range.

Comment: @sami in mysql datatype is double. question edited

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya it works with another problem: record will be save twice! and another point: is there a way to do this without casting?

Comment: Write the number as a double in the PHP code. Then no need for casting.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen thanks at all. but i want some better and principled way. we will do many things with this records and anything may be leading to confusing bugs

Comment: Then the only answer is to either keep casting everywhere and hope it works or switch to some properly strongly typed environment which doesn’t do this

Comment: @Solivan forcing the variable to use the correct data type is the principled way of handling such problems.